# Vertically rotating text animation using jquery & after some time the image should fade in & fade out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text which is vertically rotating & jumps back to its original position & again started rotating by using the slick slider in jquery. Along with that, I have an image which should display after completion of one rotation when it comes back to its original position. And these two functionalities should continuously work.

I have tried it using jquery for both the two functionalities. Everything is working properly but the slider functionality timing is not matching with the image display timing.

The sample design for the below code is:https://dribbble.com/shots/6748643-Text-Animation-for-a-Coffee-Roastery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery.scrollText.js"></script>

        <link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
             }

            .container{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background:black;
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .sightbox__slideshow {
                 text-align:left;
                 width:26vw !important;
                }

            .sightbox__slide{
                  color:red;
                  font-size:2.604vw;
                   font-weight:bold;
                    padding:0px;
                }
            .sightbox__slide p{
                 text-transform: capitalize;
                 font-size:3.604vw;
                }
            .header{
                font-size:3.604vw;
                color:white;
                font-weight:bold;
                }
            #image{
                padding: 8em 12em;
                display:none;
                background-color:black;
            }
            #image img{
                width:100%;
                height:36vw;
                background-color: white;
            }

            @media (max-width: 1440px){
                 .header{
                font-size:4.0vw;
                }
                .sightbox__slide p{
                 font-size:4.0vw;
                }
                .sightbox__slideshow {
                 width:30vw !important;
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 600px){
                 .header{
                font-size:9.333vw;
                }
                .sightbox__slide p{
                 font-size:9.333vw;
                }
                .sightbox__slideshow {
                 width:30vw !important;
                }
            }
        </style>

    </head>


    <body>

<div id="deletesuccess">

        <div class="container"> 
  <div class="first-title header">WE DESIGN</div>
<div class="sightbox__slideshow">

  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--1" id="sightbox__slide--1">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">ECLECTIC</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--2" id="sightbox__slide--2">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt"> ADAPTIVE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--3" id="sightbox__slide--3">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">INTUITIVE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--4" id="sightbox__slide--4">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">AGILE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--5" id="sightbox__slide--5">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">EMPATHATIC</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--6" id="sightbox__slide--6">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">INGENIOUS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--7" id="sightbox__slide--7">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">INTRINSIC</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--8" id="sightbox__slide--8">
    <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
    <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">IMMERSIVE</p>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="second-title header">EXPERIENCES</div>

</div>

</div>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="http://www.tucsonrefugeefest.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/C-CORE-Logo.png">
    </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
  var slider = $(".sightbox__slideshow");

  slider.slick({
    arrows: false,
    vertical:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed:70,
      pauseOnHover:false,
      draggable:false,
  });

  function jumpBack() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      slider.slick("slickGoTo", 0);
    }, 70);
  }

  slider.on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    if (currentSlide === 7) {
      jumpBack();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);


runslide();

    function runslide() {          
      $('#deletesuccess').fadeIn('fast').delay(4500).fadeOut('fast', function() {
          $('#image').fadeIn('fast').delay(300).fadeOut('fast', function() {
              runslide();
          });
      });
   }

//function runslide() {
//    setTimeout(function(){
//     $('#deletesuccess').fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('fast',function() {
//        $('#image').fadeIn('fast').delay(300).fadeOut('fast', function() {
//           runslide(); 
//        });  
//     });
//  }, 300);
//}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the timing to match with the slider fade-in fade-out & the image fade-in fade-out. The image should visible after complete one rotation & the image should fade out after 3 seconds. The process should continue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the correct answer nor a complete answer, but this could be, I think, a good way to start...just let me know if this isn't what you wanted to try (or to start to try of course)

```js
var time = 1;
var duration = 500;

var interval = setInterval(function() { 
   if (time > 7) { 
      time = 1;
     
      $("#sightbox__slide--8").slideUp();
      
      $("#deletesuccess").toggle("slow");
      $("#image").toggle("slow");

   $("#sightbox__slide--1").slideDown();
   }
   else { 
      time++;
      var toggleToHide = "#sightbox__slide--" + (time-1);
      var toggleToShow = "#sightbox__slide--" + (time);
      $(toggleToHide).slideUp();
      $(toggleToShow).slideDown();
   }
}, duration);
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wordHide {
  display:none;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
.sightbox__slideshow {
  text-align:left;
  width:26vw !important;
}

.sightbox__slide{
  color:red;
  font-size:2.604vw;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:0px;
}
.sightbox__slide p{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size:3.604vw;
}
.header{
  font-size:3.604vw;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#image{
  padding: 8em 12em;
  display:none;
  background-color:black;
}
#image img{
  width:100%;
  height:36vw;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 1440px){
  .header{
    font-size:4.0vw;
  }
  .sightbox__slide p{
    font-size:4.0vw;
  }
  .sightbox__slideshow {
    width:30vw !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
  .header{
    font-size:9.333vw;
  }
  .sightbox__slide p{
    font-size:9.333vw;
  }
  .sightbox__slideshow {
    width:30vw !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery.scrollText.js"></script>

        <link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       

    </head>


    <body>

<div id="deletesuccess">

  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="first-title header">WE DESIGN &nbsp;</div>
    <div class="sightbox__slideshow">

    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--1" id="sightbox__slide--1">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt"> ECLECTIC</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--2 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--2">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">ADAPTIVE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--3 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--3">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">INTUITIVE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--4 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--4">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">AGILE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--5 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--5">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">EMPATHATIC</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--6 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--6">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">INGENIOUS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--7 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--7">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">INTRINSIC</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sightbox__slide sightbox__slide--8 wordHide" id="sightbox__slide--8">
      <div alt="" class="sightbox__slide-img"></div>
      <p class="sightbox__slide-txt">IMMERSIVE</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="second-title header">EXPERIENCES</div>

</div>

</div>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="http://www.tucsonrefugeefest.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/C-CORE-Logo.png">
    </div> 
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please verify the above link,that i have given below. I want that design to be display like that image animation. The Link is::https://dribbble.com/shots/6748643-Text-Animation-for-a-Coffee-Roastery